# Buttons darker on Galaxy Android 3.2

Tags: java, android, button, mobile, galaxy

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab, Android version 3.2, that is displaying the default Button control much much darker. Android 3.2 doesn't do this in the emulator, it doesn't do it on a newer ICS tablet, it doesn't do it on any of our phones or in any version of the Android emulator. Has anyone encountered this? We are not doing *anything* to the button controls display wise. They are completely out of the box controls. 
Is there a fix that doesn't require custom coloring all our button controls? We're kind of stuck, because we can't reproduce it anywhere but the tablet it's happening on is our final QA approver, and she's a stickler for this sort of thing (it's an enterprise app we're trying to get going).

Edit: Looks for sure like it's setting a transparency on the buttons that none of the other devices are, rather than using a different color.

Edit: Here is a screen shot. Specifically, the Submit Shipping Selection.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you are seeing? Are you explicitly using `Theme.Holo`?

Comment: Are you explicitly using `Theme.Holo`? If not, try that.

Comment: My main developer doesn't know. Again, we just dropped them right out of the box. I'll do some digging.

Comment: There was no theme set at all. 
We're targeting 2.2, so I can't default to Theme.Holo. I tried default to theme (android:theme="@android:style/Theme in the ApplicationManifest) but it's still not working. It appears what it's doing is there is some transparency on the button that the rest of our devices don't have, because on the home screen they are blue and our background is blue. This button thing is the only visual difference, and it's only doing it on 3.2 on this device.

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to 2.2?! Target 4.0.3 like everyone else! Your users will appreciate the holo theme a lot more

Comment: You may be having similar issues on other devices, ones beyond what you are testing. Device manufacturers have *carte blanche* to go in and change whatever they want with themes... except that they must leave `Theme.Holo` alone. You can either simply try `android:targetSdkVersion="14"` (probably a good idea anyway), or change your build target and expressly use `Theme.Holo` on API Level 11+ devices, or just leave it alone (all buttons should look that way on that device).